# Jquery Ajax element.ready possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax, domready

I would like to catch some attributes in a content but this content is updated by Ajax.
The issue is that my function trigger **before** the whole content is displayed, so I don't catch anything.

I want my function to wait for the end of the ajax function.

I thought, there was an option like :

```
$(element).ready(function() { 
blablabla;
});
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your function in the success section of the $.ajax function?
For example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    $(element).addClass("done");
    yourFunction();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the original DOM from within the success handler, so you can write a success handler that updates the original DOM, generates the new DOM elements however you want and then append them when you're ready so I don't see the point of this.